# How do I join tables to choose the maximum row in the joined table?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, greatest-n-per-group, outer-join

I have two tables and I would like to left join them on an attribute, but rather than taking all matching rows in the second table I would like to choose only the entry with the highest number (latest date, etc.) in a certain column. How do I express this result in SQL?

Here's a simplified example to clarify my question.

```
Table `colors`
| color |
+-------+
| red   |
| green |
| blue  |


Table `inventory`
| color | value | shape    |
+-------+-------+----------|
| red   | 1     | square   |
| red   | 2     | circle   |
| green | 7     | triangle |


Desired output:
| color | value | shape    |
+-------+-------+----------|
| red   | 2     | circle   |
| green | 7     | triangle |
| blue  | NULL  | NULL     |
```

My tables are fairly large so ideally a solution would be reasonably efficient. (There's no need for fine tuning, just trying to avoid double joins which could become huge.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b75c/6

```
SELECT c.*, i.value, i.shape
FROM colors c
LEFT JOIN inventory i
ON c.color = i.color
LEFT JOIN inventory i_
ON i.color = i_.color
  AND i.value<i_.value
WHERE  i_.color IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b75c/8

```
SELECT i.value, i.shape
FROM inventory i
LEFT JOIN inventory i_
ON i.color = i_.color
  AND i.value<i_.value
WHERE  i_.color IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But is there a way to avoid double joins?

Comment: If you don't mind to lose `blue` in result. In that case you can have 1 self join.

Comment: I could live with dropping blue (I can always `UNION` it back) but I'd like to avoid joining inventory to itself. With 100k entries the intermediate table would have 10 billion entries...

Comment: this joins should work much faster than union

Comment: @Charles Relational databases are very good at joins, that's the "relational" part. If `color` and `value` are indexed (color should be as a key), it will do something much more efficient than brute force 10 billion operations.

Comment: @Charles yes, you can do [single joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/1057527)

Answer (score 2):

```
select c.color, i2.value, i2.shape
from colors c
left join 
(
   select color, max(value) as value
   from inventory 
   group by color
) i on c.color = i.color
left join inventory i2 on i2.color = i.color
                      and i2.value = i.value
```

Comment: This works, but is there a way to avoid a double join?

Comment: @Charles A double join likely won't be a performance problem. `color` will be indexed as a foreign and primary key so both joins will be very fast. Indexing `value` might speed up the subselect.

Comment: @Charles To improve performance you could replace the subselect with a [materialized view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view), basically a cache of the subquery that looks like a table. It also makes queries easier to read, rather than joining on a subquery you'd join on the name of the view, perhaps `best_colors`, like any other table. But MySQL doesn't support materialized views. However, you can create your own [summary tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) and keep them updated in various ways depending on the nature of the data.